# Are there reactions operated at high temperature at industrial level?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, reaction-control

Temperature is an important parameter when you deal with a chemical reaction, first of all $\Delta G$ and $\Delta G^\circ$ depend on temperature, and as a consequence the spontaneity of a reaction depends on temperature. Second, also the equilibrium constant $K$ depends on temperature so, it is possible to modify the reaction yield by varying it.

Finally, the kinetic constant $K_{V}$, and so the reaction speed, are related to temperature. Said that, I was wondering if at industrial level, there are some important reactions which are operated at high temperature (I mean at least more than $\pu{40 °C})$ in order to obtain at least one, or more of the effects I've written (or some other that I don't know). Of course, I also include reactions such as electrolysis and electrochemistry reactions.

Comment: The temperature of all production reactions in industry is chosen by economic consideration of the combination of kinetics and equilibrium.  Other examples are ammonia synthesis and oxidation of cyclohexane to produce adipic acid.

Comment: The Haber-Bosch process for producing ammonia works at both high temperature and pressure for both kinetic and thermodynamic reasons.

Comment: If you wanna talk about electrochemistry, write it in title, not last sentence! BTW what industry thinks as high temps is at least order of magnitude higher.

Answer (score 1):

The cracking reactions transforming heavy fuel, tar, domestic or heavy oils into lighter molecules like gasoline, kerosene or white spirits, they are all carried out at temperatures higher than 200 °C. The electrolysis of alumina to produce metallic aluminium is done at about 960 °C. The production of iron from ore and charcoal is done in a blast furnace at 1400 °C